# MVC3 Post Unobtrusive Client Validation but Before Submit Hook available?

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

Using the `jquery.validate` ([1.8.1](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)) library and the ASP MVC3 RTM `jquery.validate.ubobtrusive` library, I'm wondering if there is a hook available where one could inject some additional logic to occur post-validation, but before the actual form is submitted.

In other words: the form is being submitted, the validation runs (doing whatever it normally does), validation finds no reason to stop the form from submitting, *Run My Code Here*, then submit as normal.

I know I could handle the form's `submit` event and do something like:

```
$('#MyForm').submit(function() {
    if (!$(this).valid())
       return false;

    // My Code Here
}
```

... calling the validation myself and then, if successful, put in my own logic.  But I feel this is dirty.  How do I know that this is the only code going on in the jquery.validate's submit handler?  Even if this is the only code running, do I really want to duplicate it?  I would much rather not have to mirror what the validation library does on submit; I would just like to inject myself after the validation happens, but before the form submits -- like binding to a mythical `$('#MyForm').lastPossibleMomentBeforeSubmit(function() { // My Code Here });` 
event.

Any pointers on where this "My Code Here" should be go?

Answer (score 1):

If you were just using jquery.validate you could use the success call back like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#MyForm').validate({
       success : function(error) {
           // additional logic
       }
    });
});
```

However, because you're using jquery.validate.ubobtrusive sadly this can't be done directly because jquery.validate.ubobtrusive hides the call to .validate from you internally.

Instead you need to get the settings/options object that jquery.validate.ubobtrusive passed to .validate, capture it's existing success handler, and replace it with your own that calls the original and does own additional functionality like this:

```
$(function () {
            var settings = $('form').data('validator').settings,
                originalSuccess = settings.success;
            settings.success = function (error) {
                originalSuccess(error);
                // additional logic
            };
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MyFormform").validator().bind("onSuccess", function(e, els) {
         //Code to run after validation succeeds
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure what framework you are referencing here.  Do you have a link to this onSuccess method documentation?  Doing just $('#MyForm').validator() is an error, so I'm not sure what you are getting at here.  Are you sure this is for jquery.validate / jquery.validate.ubobtrusive?